# How to apply images on spark numericstepper using stylesheet

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash

I want to customize the images on increment and decrement buttons in spark numericstepper and I trying the following in my css file. But it doesnot work for spark numericstepper.

```
s|NumericStepper
{
 downArrowDisabledSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/downArrowDisabledSkin.png");
 downArrowDownSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/downArrowDownSkin.png");
 downArrowOverSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/downArrowOverSkin.png");
 downArrowUpSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/downArrowUpSkin.png");
 upArrowDisabledSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/upArrowDisabledSkin.png");
 upArrowDownSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/upArrowDownSkin.png");
 upArrowOverSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/upArrowOverSkin.png");
 upArrowUpSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/upArrowUpSkin.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you skin a halo (mx) NumericStepper but it won't work for the spark NumericStepper.

You have to create a new spark skin and use BitmapImage in it.

Before that, I suggest you read more about the new spark architecture

Comment: Thanks PeZ. I also have created two different skins for increment and decrement buttons and has added a BitmapImage in those skins like this. <s:BitmapImage id="imageDispley"
       source.down="@Embed('assets/componentImages/upArrowDownSkin.png')"
       source.up="@Embed('assets/componentImages/upArrowUpSkin.png')"
       source.over="@Embed('assets/componentImages/upArrowOverSkin.png')"
       source.disabled="@Embed('assets/componentImages/upArrowDisabledSkin.png')"/> But i want to reference css here instead. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe using the getStyle method :
source.down="getStyle('upArrowDownSkin')" 
and in your CSS:
upArrowDownSkin:Embed(source="assets/componentImages/upArrowDownSkin.png")

I haven't tried it though

Comment: Here is an example : http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/migrating-to-flex-4-using-skins/